# iPhone : Which parsing method is best to use?

Tags: iphone

i want to know which parsing method is best to use among

- Simple XML parsing
- JSON Parsing.

i am new to iPhone programming...thats why i want to know

what is the advantages of JSON parsing ?

when to use JSON Parsing ?

thanking in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking about which parsing method to use, the answer would simply be "one that match your data". JSON and XML does not use the same schemas, so you would not be able to choose freely.

On the other hand if you are actually asking which data format to use, then I'll suggest having a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473080/soap-rest-or-just-xml-for-objective-c-iphone-vs-server-solution).